# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory even if libcublas.so.9.0 exists in path

Tags: tensorflow

My machine info:

- nvcc --version:

  `nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
  Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
  Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
  Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176`
- cuda driver version

  - version - 9.2
  - file - nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-rhel7-396.26-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
- cat /etc/redhat-release: **CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)**

*cat .bashrc* includes the following

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
CUDA_HOME=$CUDA_HOME:/usr/local/cuda
```

After this If I try to import torch or torchvision, it's working fine. But I import tensorflow, it's not importing

My tensorflow version are the following:

- tensorboard==1.8.0
- tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0

I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

But `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` has the following:

- libcublas_device.a
- libcublas.so
- libcublas.so.9.0
- libcublas.so.9.0.176
- libcublas_static.a

I'm not able to find out what is wrong. Does permission has something to do with this ?. Later I changed the owner and permission of above files to current and 755. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` ?? No?

Comment: @Patwie `/usr/local/cuda` is a link file to `/datadrive/abhisek/cuda-9.0/`. Anyway I changed it. `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`: `:/usr/local/cuda/lib64`. But same error.

Comment: And `libcublas.so` is a symlink to `libcublas.so.9.0` and  `libcublas.so.9.0` a symlink to `libcublas.so.9.0.176` ? You did not copy, paste and overwrite these "*.so"-files? And `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=datadrive/abhisek/cuda-9.0/lib64 python` reproduces the same error with TensorFlow (in other words: `.bashrc` is really executed)?

Comment: I'm not doing any overwriting or copy pasting. While installing cuda it asks where to put the installation files and where to create the link files. The only link file is `/usr/local/cuda` to `datadrive/abhisek/cuda-9.0`. And `.bashrc` is being executed as I'm restarting the session after changes. In other words `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`: `:/usr/local/cuda/lib64`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the mentioned path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH as:

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: `/usr/local/cuda` is a link file to `/datadrive/abhisek/cuda-9.0`. Anyway I changed it, still no luck. same error!

Comment: Do you see the correct output when you call os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] in python?